# What firewall rules are necessary for SQL Server Multi-Server Administration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

What firewall rules are necessary for SQL Server Multi-Server Administration?  This is for an environment where database servers are in different 'zones', with all traffic blocked by default.

We've opened up SQL Server traffic (i.e. 1433/TCP and 1434/UDP) but it appears more is needed for Multi-Server Administration.  Getting the error 'The RPC Server is unavailable' when attempting to add a new target server.  Worked through the troubleshooting steps up through firewall rules at: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4494.windows-server-troubleshooting-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable.aspx

The list of SQL Server TCP and UDP Ports does not mention multi-server administration:
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/sql-server-tcp-and-udp-ports

Answer (score 1):

From the link you had to sqlmag, there's a link to another Microsoft article detailing the ports in more details: "[Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)".

That article contains a section on RPC:

> **Special Considerations for Port 135**
>
> When you use RPC with TCP/IP or with UDP/IP as the transport, inbound
>   ports are frequently dynamically assigned to system services as
>   required; TCP/IP and UDP/IP ports that are larger than port 1024 are
>   used. These are frequently informally referred to as "random RPC
>   ports." In these cases, RPC clients rely on the RPC endpoint mapper to
>   tell them which dynamic ports were assigned to the server. For some
>   RPC-based services, you can configure a specific port instead of
>   letting RPC assign one dynamically. You can also restrict the range of
>   ports that RPC dynamically assigns to a small range, regardless of the
>   service. Because port 135 is used for many services it is frequently
>   attacked by malicious users. When opening port 135, consider
>   restricting the scope of the firewall rule.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you much for narrowing down to that.  I'm still struggling to translate that paragraph into some firewall rules I can document.  Master->Target TCP 135, Target->Master TCP 1024 or greater?